# My iframe won't fit in Facebook

Tags: facebook-iframe

I am making a basic website to use as an iframe on facebook, but for some reason my page won't fit. Despite its 510pixel width, facebook cuts it off and and adds a vertical scroll bar.  Here is what it should look like: http://missinglinksocialmedia.com/thecody/codyfeature.html.  Here is what facebook turns it into: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Your-Business/158309827551078?sk=app_218960891469608

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of spacing between the pictures. Try it with a few pixels less.